# On a scale of 1 to 10 how far is this manifold from being a normal bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

**(DIS)-CLAIMER**: All the manifolds considered in this post are completely humble and have no additional structure beyond the smooth structure.

Let $Y$ be a submanifold of $M$ and let $(-)^0$ denote the annihilator.

I claim (and about to prove hopefully) that $NY = \{(m,\omega)\in T^*M : m \in Y, \omega \in (T_m Y)^0 \}$ can be given a natural structure as a submanifold of $T^*M$.

(So before the storm of notation comes...) Here's my question :

**On a scale of 1 to ten how far is $NY$ from being a normal bundle?**

Furtheremore, i'd like to know **how come this manifold is canonical with a unique smooth structure** (depending on the original atlas of course) whereas the usual Normal bundle depends on a choice of inner product?

**The proof** (I am so very terribly sorry about the length):

Let $y \in Y$ and let $(\phi,U)$ be an adapted chart at point the  $y$. 
Meaning $\phi(U \cap Y)=\phi(U) \cap\mathbb{R}^k \times\{0\}^{n-k}$ and $\phi(y)=0$ where $n$ and $k$ are the dimensions of $M$ and $Y$ respectively.

We denote the tangent map of $\phi$ at $m$ by $T_m \phi$ and the cotangent bundle of $M$ by $T^*M$. Define $T^*\phi: T^*M \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ to be the map:

$$T^*\phi :(m,\omega) \mapsto (\phi(m), (T_m\phi^*)^{-1} \omega)$$

We look at the image of the set $NY = \{(m,\omega)\in T^*M : m \in Y, \omega \in (T_m Y)^0 \}$ where $(-)^0$ is the annihilator.

$$T^*\phi(NY)= \{(\phi(m),(T_m\phi^*)^{-1}\omega)\in T^*M : m \in Y, \omega \in (T_m Y)^0 \}$$

Let $\pi : \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k} \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ be the natural projection. Clearly $\ker T_m (\pi o \phi)=T_mY$.

The annihilator of the kernel is the image of the dual so:  $\omega \in (T_mY)^0 \implies \omega = T_m(\pi o \phi)^* \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in (\mathbb{R}^{n-k})^*$ substituting we get:

$$(T_m\phi^*)^{-1}\omega=(T_m\phi^*)^{-1}T_m(\pi o  \phi)^* \alpha = (T_m\pi)^*\alpha$$

Now $Im (T_m \pi^*)=(\ker T_m \pi)^0= \{0\}^k \times\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. So basically what we proved is that $T^*\phi$ is in fact an adapted chart of $NY$. Why? Because:

$$T^*\phi(U \cap NY)= T^*\phi(U) \cap \mathbb{R}^k \times\{0\}^{n-k} \times \{0\}^k\times \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$$

And the image of the right side under the right projections is $\mathbb{R}^n$. So $dim(NY)=n$ which is exactly what we want for a normal bundle!

Comment: +1, also for your refereshingly original and humorous style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle you're denoting by $NY$ is called the [conormal bundle of $Y$](http://planetmath.org/conormalbundle), more commonly denoted by $N^*Y$. It is indeed a smooth subbundle of $T^*M$, defined independently of any choice of Riemannian metric. As @Mariano observed, if you put a Riemannian metric on $M$, you obtain a normal bundle $N^gY$ (the orthogonal complement of $TY$ in $TM|_Y$), which is naturally isomorphic to $N^*Y$.

With respect to the natural symplectic structure on $T^*M$, the conormal bundle is a Lagrangian submanifold. It plays an extremely important role in PDE theory and microlocal analysis. For example, if $M$ is a manifold with boundary and $Y=\partial M$, the class of distributions on $M$ whose [wave front set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_front_set) lies in $N^*M$, called ***conormal distributions***, is important for studying singular boundary value problems.

Comment: Thanks for another piece of the puzzle! Is there a natural way (without a metric) to define a smooth structure on the quotient bundle $TM|Y/Y$?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Given any smooth bundle $E\to M$ containing a smooth subbundle $F\to M$, there's a natural smooth structure on the quotient bundle $E/F\to M$. To define it, just choose local trivializations of $E$ that send fibers of $F$ to $\mathbb R^k\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb R^n$, and define the local trivializations of $E/F$ by following these local trivializations of $E$ by the map $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^{n-k}$ given by projection onto the last $n-k$ components.

Comment: Wow! marvelous. last question (I promise): What if i repeat the same construction on the set  $NY = \{(m,v)\in T^*M : m \in Y, v \in (T_m^*Y)^0 \}$. Where $(T_m^*Y)^0 = \{v \in T_mM: \omega(v)=0 \; \forall \; \omega \in (T_m^*Y)$} Will i get the same result as yours?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, because by the definition you gave, $(T^*_mY)^0$ is not a subset of $T_m^*M$.

Comment: Yeah i know. The mistake was in a different place. What i meant was the set $\{(m,v)\in TM : m \in Y, v \in (T_m^*Y)^0 \}$ which is a subset of $TM$. Then i continue with the construction dualing everything. (The co-conormal bundle).

Comment: Now the subset of $TM$ that you've defined is just another way of writing $TY$.  So yes, you can do this, and what you get is the quotient bundle $TM|_Y/TY$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I just wasn't sure you get the same smooth structure with both methods. Thanks for everything! Your book on topological manifolds is terrific by the way!

Answer (score 2):

If you fix a Riemannian metric on $M$, then you have an isomorphism $TM\cong T^*M$, and under that isomorphism your $NY$, which is the subbundle of $(T^*M)|_Y$ which annihilates $TY$, is the same thing as the orthogonal complement of $TY$ in $(TM)|_Y$. This last bundle is, precisely, the normal bundle of $Y$ in $M$.

Comment: Can you always put a Riemann metric on a manifold? If not is this a known generalization?
Anyway your answer is exactly the assurance i needed. Thanks!

Comment: Ever (paracompact) smooth manifold has a Riemannian metric. This should be proved in pretty much every textbook — Warner's, for example.

Comment: Ah great. I never realy delved into Riemannian geometry before. I have a tendency to learn stuff in the wrong order.

Comment: Wait a sec, one last question. How come $NY$'s smooth structure is uniquely determined by the atlas while the usual Normal Bundle structure depends on the choice of metric?

Comment: @Saal: that's an excellent question. Every submanifold $Y\subset M$ has a very intrinsic normal bundle $ \nu(Y)=\frac {T(M)|Y}{T(Y)}$ which only depends on the humble (hum, hum,...) differential structures on $M$ and $Y$.  Whenever you put a Riemannian structure $g$ on $M$ you get a "concrete"  normal bundle $N^g(Y)\subset T(M)|Y$ on $Y$. That all these concrete normal bundles are isomorphic when $g$ runs through the zillion Riemannian structures on $M$ is indeed an astonishing fact, best explained by their being all isomorphic to the intrinsic  $\nu(Y)$.